# Joining Rx Streams

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive

I'm trying to model an Rx query that is not trivial (to me):

- In a room there are Men and Women.
- They enter and leave the room, and while in the room sometimes they change their location.
- Each man can look at one (or zero) woman at a given time.
- Each man has the following properties:

  ```
  class Man
  {
    public const int LookingAtNobody = 0;
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Location { get; set; }
    public int LookingAt { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Each woman has the following properties:

  ```
  class Woman
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Location { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- To represent the Men we have `IObservable<IObservable<Man>>`, and to represent the Women we have `IObservable<IObservable<Woman>>`.

How would you use Rx to generate vectors from men to the women they're looking at: `IObservable<IObservable<Tuple<double,double>>>` ?

To help, here are a few unit-tests for some simple cases:

```
public class Tests : ReactiveTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Puzzle1()
    {
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

        var m1 = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            OnNext(100, new Man { Id = 1, Location = 1.0, LookingAt = Man.LookingAtNobody }),
            OnNext(200, new Man { Id = 1, Location = 2.0, LookingAt = 10 }),
            OnCompleted<Man>(300));

        var w1 = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            OnNext(150, new Woman { Id = 10, Location = 10.0 }),
            OnNext(250, new Woman { Id = 10, Location = 20.0 }),
            OnCompleted<Woman>(350));

        var men = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(OnNext(50, m1));
        var women = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(OnNext(50, w1));

        var results = runQuery(scheduler, women, men);

        var innerResults = (from msg in results
                            where msg.Value.HasValue
                            select msg.Value.Value).ToArray();
        var expectedVector1 = new[]
                       {
                           OnNext(200, Tuple.Create(2.0, 10.0)),
                           OnNext(250, Tuple.Create(2.0, 20.0)),
                           OnCompleted<Tuple<double,double>>(300),
                       };
        ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(expectedVector1, innerResults[0]);
    }
    [Test]
    public void Puzzle2()
    {
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

        var m1 = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            OnNext(100, new Man { Id = 1, Location = 1.0, LookingAt = Man.LookingAtNobody }),
            OnNext(200, new Man { Id = 1, Location = 2.0, LookingAt = 10 }),
            OnCompleted<Man>(400));

        var w1 = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            OnNext(150, new Woman { Id = 10, Location = 10.0 }),
            OnNext(250, new Woman { Id = 10, Location = 20.0 }),
            OnCompleted<Woman>(350));

        var men = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(OnNext(50, m1));
        var women = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(OnNext(50, w1));

        var results = runQuery(scheduler, women, men);

        var innerResults = (from msg in results
                            where msg.Value.HasValue
                            select msg.Value.Value).ToArray();
        var expectedVector1 = new[]
                       {
                           OnNext(200, Tuple.Create(2.0, 10.0)),
                           OnNext(250, Tuple.Create(2.0, 20.0)),
                           OnCompleted<Tuple<double,double>>(350),
                       };
        ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(expectedVector1, innerResults[0]);
    }
    [Test]
    public void Puzzle3()
    {
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

        var m1 = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            OnNext(100, new Man { Id = 1, Location = 1.0, LookingAt = Man.LookingAtNobody }),
            OnNext(200, new Man { Id = 1, Location = 2.0, LookingAt = 10 }),
            OnNext(300, new Man { Id = 1, Location = 2.0, LookingAt = Man.LookingAtNobody }),
            OnCompleted<Man>(400));

        var w1 = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            OnNext(150, new Woman { Id = 10, Location = 10.0 }),
            OnNext(250, new Woman { Id = 10, Location = 20.0 }),
            OnCompleted<Woman>(350));

        var men = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(OnNext(50, m1));
        var women = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(OnNext(50, w1));

        var results = runQuery(scheduler, women, men);

        var innerResults = (from msg in results
                            where msg.Value.HasValue
                            select msg.Value.Value).ToArray();
        var expectedVector1 = new[]
                       {
                           OnNext(200, Tuple.Create(2.0, 10.0)),
                           OnNext(250, Tuple.Create(2.0, 20.0)),
                           OnCompleted<Tuple<double,double>>(300),
                       };
        ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(expectedVector1, innerResults[0]);
    }
    [Test]
    public void Puzzle4()
    {
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

        var m1 = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            OnNext(100, new Man { Id = 1, Location = 1.0, LookingAt = Man.LookingAtNobody }),
            OnNext(200, new Man { Id = 1, Location = 2.0, LookingAt = 10 }),
            OnNext(300, new Man { Id = 1, Location = 3.0, LookingAt = 20 }),
            OnNext(400, new Man { Id = 1, Location = 4.0, LookingAt = 20 }),
            OnCompleted<Man>(500));

        var w1 = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            OnNext(150, new Woman { Id = 10, Location = 10.0 }),
            OnNext(250, new Woman { Id = 10, Location = 20.0 }),
            OnCompleted<Woman>(350));
        var w2 = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            OnNext(155, new Woman { Id = 20, Location = 100.0 }),
            OnNext(255, new Woman { Id = 20, Location = 200.0 }),
            OnNext(355, new Woman { Id = 20, Location = 300.0 }),
            OnCompleted<Woman>(455));

        var men = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(OnNext(50, m1));
        var women = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(OnNext(50, w1), OnNext(50, w2));

        var results = runQuery(scheduler, women, men);

        var innerResults = (from msg in results
                            where msg.Value.HasValue
                            select msg.Value.Value).ToArray();
        var expectedVector1 = new[]
                       {
                           OnNext(200, Tuple.Create(2.0, 10.0)),
                           OnNext(250, Tuple.Create(2.0, 20.0)),
                           OnCompleted<Tuple<double,double>>(300),
                       };
        var expectedVector2 = new[]
                       {
                           OnNext(300, Tuple.Create(3.0, 200.0)),
                           OnNext(355, Tuple.Create(3.0, 300.0)),
                           OnNext(400, Tuple.Create(4.0, 300.0)),
                           OnCompleted<Tuple<double,double>>(455),
                       };
        ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(expectedVector1, innerResults[0]);
        ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(expectedVector2, innerResults[1]);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Recorded<Notification<IList<Recorded<Notification<Tuple<double, double>>>>>>> runQuery(TestScheduler scheduler, IObservable<IObservable<Woman>> women, IObservable<IObservable<Man>> men)
    {
        // assuming nested sequences are hot
        var vectors =
            from manDuration in men
            join womanDuration in women on manDuration equals womanDuration
            select from man in manDuration
                   join woman in womanDuration on manDuration equals womanDuration
                   where man.LookingAt == woman.Id
                   select Tuple.Create(man.Location, woman.Location);

        var query = vectors.Select(vectorDuration =>
        {
            var vectorResults = scheduler.CreateObserver<Tuple<double, double>>();
            vectorDuration.Subscribe(vectorResults);
            return vectorResults.Messages;
        });

        var results = scheduler.Start(() => query, 0, 0, 1000).Messages;
        return results;
    }
}
```

(note: this question was cross posted to the Rx forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/e73ae4e2-68c3-459a-a5b6-ea957b205abe)

Comment: DAT  IEnumerable<Recorded<Notification<IList<Recorded<Notification<Tuple<double, double>>>>>>>

Comment: Your post to the MSDN forum, and the amount of chatter it created demonstrates that this is not a good question for a Q&A site.

Comment: "Don't cross the streams" - Dr. Egon Spengler

Comment: @ CSJ, Jeff : Made my day!

Comment: Approach is wrong.. man should not have 'looking at woman' property. should have 'looking at location' property. but if you insist on man to have that property - why woman have location property in the 1st place??

Comment: The location of the women is dynamic. We are interested in a stream (observable) of vectors between the location of men and the location of the women that they look at.

Comment: I don't understand the question - what is the use of Rx supposed to accomplish in this example?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the objective is to create an observable of “follow observables”, where a “follow observable” begins when a man starts looking at a woman, and ends when the man stops looking at the woman. The “follow observable” should consist of tuples of the most recent locations of the man and woman.

The idea here is to use `CombineLatest`, which will take two observables, and when any of them produces a value, the combinator is evaluated for the two most recent values of the observables, which produces a value in the combined observable. However, `CombineLatest` completes only when both observables have been completed. In this case, we want to complete the observable when any of the two sources completes. In order to do so, we define the following extension method (I don’t believe such a method exists already, but there might be an easier solution):

```
public static IObservable<TSource>
  UntilCompleted<TSource, TWhile>(this IObservable<TSource> source,
                                       IObservable<TWhile> lifetime)
{
  return Observable.Create<TSource>(observer =>
  {
    var subscription = source.Subscribe(observer);
    var limiter = lifetime.Subscribe(next => { }, () =>
    {
      subscription.Dispose();
      observer.OnCompleted();
    });
    return new CompositeDisposable(subscription, limiter);
  });
}
```

This method is like `TakeUntil`, but it instead of taking until `lifetime` produces a value, it takes until `lifetime` completes. We can also define a simple extension method that takes the first streak that satisfies a predicate:

```
public static IObservable<TSource>
  Streak<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source,
                       Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
  return source.SkipWhile(x => !predicate(x)).TakeWhile(predicate);
}
```

Now for the final query, we combine all men with all women using `CombineLatest`, and complete that observable early using `UntilCompleted`. To get the “follow observables”, we select the streak where the man is looking at the woman. Then we simply map that to a tuple of locations.

```
var vectors =
  from manDuration in men
  from womanDuration in women
  select manDuration
  .CombineLatest(womanDuration, (m, w) => new { Man = m, Woman = w })
  .UntilCompleted(womanDuration)
  .UntilCompleted(manDuration)
  .Streak(pair => pair.Man.LookingAt == pair.Woman.Id)
  .Select(pair => Tuple.Create(pair.Man.Location, pair.Woman.Location));
```

This passes all of your tests, but it does not handle the scenario where a man looks at woman 10 for a while, then at 20 for a while, and then at 10 for a while again; only the *first* streak is used. To observe all streaks, we can use the following extension method, which returns an observable of streaks:

```
public static IObservable<IObservable<TSource>>
  Streaks<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source,
                        Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
  return Observable.Create<IObservable<TSource>>(observer =>
  {
    ReplaySubject<TSource> subject = null;
    bool previous = false;
    return source.Subscribe(x =>
    {
      bool current = predicate(x);
      if (!previous && current)
      {
        subject = new ReplaySubject<TSource>();
        observer.OnNext(subject);
      }
      if (previous && !current) subject.OnCompleted();
      if (current) subject.OnNext(x);
      previous = current;
    }, () =>
    {
      if (subject != null) subject.OnCompleted();
      observer.OnCompleted();
    });
  });
}
```

By subscribing only once to the source stream, and by using a `ReplaySubject`, this method works for hot as well as cold observables. Now for the final query, we select all streaks as follows:

```
var vectors =
  from manDuration in men
  from womanDuration in women
  from streak in manDuration
  .CombineLatest(womanDuration, (m, w) => new { Man = m, Woman = w })
  .UntilCompleted(womanDuration)
  .UntilCompleted(manDuration)
  .Streaks(pair => pair.Man.LookingAt == pair.Woman.Id)
  select streak.Select(pair =>
    Tuple.Create(pair.Man.Location, pair.Woman.Location));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand why you're modeling the stream of locations of both the men and the women as an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` instead of just an `IObservable<T>`, but this might work:

```
public static IObservable<Tuple<double, double>> GetLocationsObservable(IObservable<IObservable<Man>> menObservable, 
                                                                            IObservable<IObservable<Woman>> womenObservable)
{
    return Observable.CombineLatest(
        menObservable.Switch(),
        womenObservable.Switch(),
        (man, woman) => new {man, woman})
            .Where(manAndWoman => manAndWoman.man.LookingAt == manAndWoman.woman.Id)
            .Select(manAndWoman => Tuple.Create(manAndWoman.man.Location, manAndWoman.woman.Location));
}
```

The switches essentially "switch" to the new observable when it is pushed, which flattens the streams. The where and select are fairly straightforward.

I have a sneaking suspicion I'm misunderstanding something about the requirements, but I figured I'd submit my answer just in case it helps.